# 3G iphone touches less responsive than other devices?

Tags: iphone, touch, swipe

I'm developing a game for the iPhone and I've noticed a difference specific to the 3G iPhone.  I have been testing the software all 3 versions of the iPhone - 2G, 3G and 3GS.  The 2G and the 3GS work the same, but I find on the 3G that the swipes and touches are much slower to respond.  At first I thought it might just be a CPU issue, but the 2G iphone is slower and works the same as the 3GS.

Is this a known issue?  Is the 3G iphone known for having a different touch sensitivity?

Comment: restart and check again.

Comment: This is more of a hardware issue, and is not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you restart your device and see if it is more responsive.

I personnally did not feel any difference in my games applications.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the game was just chewing up CPU.  When the iPhone is running at load, the touch performance goes down, making it seem sticky and less responsive.  I've tuned the app and it now works the same on all the machines.